# Using '#type"=>'container' to create a div wrapper around nested elements?

Tags: theming

From my reading a render array can define a wrapper div by using the `'#type'=>'container'`. I am inserting a render array in the `page_alter` hook function in the `page_bottom` region. It appears that the container type does not work in this case. The code below does not wrap the two `#markup`elements with the div wrapper but instead outputs the `div` then the content at the same level.

```
$page['page_bottom']["notices"] = array(
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'id' => array('notices'),
  ),
);

$page['page_bottom']["notices"]['notices-placeholder'] = array(
  '#suffix' => "<div id='notices-placeholder'>",
  '#prefix' => '</div>',
);

$page['page_bottom']["notices"]['notices-tab'] = array(
  '#markup' => '<div class="notices-notification-tab">NOTICES &nbsp;<span class="notices-count">10</span></div>',
);
```

What I want is the following.

```
<div id="notices">
    <div id="notices-placeholder"></div>
    <div  class="notices-notification-tab">NOTICES....</div>
</div>
```

What I get is the following.

```
<div id="notices"></div>
<div id="notices-placeholder"></div>
<div  class="notices-notification-tab">NOTICES....</div>
```

--- Added
I did try `#children` earlier in the day and it didn't work as well. Before I left for the day I also tried with

```
$page['page_bottom']["notices"]['notices-placeholder'] = array(
    '#suffix' => "<div id='notices-placeholder'>",
    '#markup'=>"Empty String", // added to see what it would do
    '#prefix' => '</div>',
);
```

This resulted in a completely out of sync html with the `#markup` tag being outside the `#prefix`/`#suffix`. I don't have the results on me now to post but if you try it you will see the results for your self.

Comment: You have a bug in your code :) Your #suffix should be #prefix, and your #prefix should be #suffix. Currently you have `'#prefix' => '</div>'`, so this closes your container. It becomes more clear if you use a different html tag for the prefix/suffix stuff, e.g. `'<article>'`. Then you would get `<div id="notices"></article>`.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to obtain what you wanted using the following code.

```
  $page['page_bottom']["notices"] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'id' => array('notices'),
    ),
  );

  $page['page_bottom']["notices"]['notices-placeholder'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'id' => array('notices-placeholder'),
    ),
  );

  $page['page_bottom']["notices"]['notices-tab'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<div class="notices-notification-tab">NOTICES &nbsp;<span class="notices-count">10</span></div>',
  );
```

The output I obtain using that code as implementation of `hook_page_alter()` is the following.

```
<div id="notices"><div id="notices-placeholder"></div><div class="notices-notification-tab">NOTICES &nbsp;<span class="notices-count">10</span></div></div>
```

I tried using your code, and setting `$page['page_bottom']["notices"]['#tree']` to `TRUE`, or setting `$page['page_bottom']["notices"]['notices-placeholder']['#type']` to `'markup'`, but I always obtained the same result as you.

The only explanation I have is that, using your code, [theme_container()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_container/7) (the function defined as theme wrapper for the "container" element) doesn't get any value for `$element['#children']`. That would explain why the container HTML output doesn't contain any children element, as the code executed by `theme_container()` is the following one.

```
  $element = $variables['element'];

  // Special handling for form elements.
  if (isset($element['#array_parents'])) {
    // Assign an html ID.
    if (!isset($element['#attributes']['id'])) {
      $element['#attributes']['id'] = $element['#id'];
    }
    // Add the 'form-wrapper' class.
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-wrapper';
  }

  return '<div' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $element['#children'] . '</div>';
```

#### References

- [system_element_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_element_info/7)
- [drupal_render_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render_page/7)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did try with #children as well with no luck. I also tried with the

$page['page_bottom']["notices"]['notices-placeholder'] = array(
  '#suffix' => "<div id='notices-placeholder'>",
  '#prefix' => '</div>',
);

Comment: The first snippet I shown works.

Answer (score 1):

Change suffix and prefix

$page['page_bottom']["notices"]['notices-placeholder'] = array(
  '#prefix' => "",
  '#suffix' => '',
);

Comment: Your answer is correct. Perhaps express it in a bit more detail :)

Answer (score -1):

you have to render the $page : return drupal_render($page)